# What to do with hidden gems while reviewing?

Tags: discussion

While reviewing Late answers, it is asking to "Check for Hidden Gems".

If we get some hidden gem, how can we help them shine, apart from upvoting?

Comment: MSE duplicate: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/152084/examples-of-hidden-gems-in-late-answers

Comment: It's a small, purple diamond that's hidden somewhere. If you click it, it shows you a unicorn and grants you 10K reputation points. More seriously, "hidden gems" is an [English idiom](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/237652/whats-an-alternative-for-hidden-gem), meaning somethign like _"something valuable that isn't obvious at first sight"_.

Comment: okay cool. So what do we do with them apart from upvote?

Comment: You refine them so they shine, and upvote them.

Comment: You can share a link to the question on Facebook, Twitter, etc. so it gets more exposure.

Comment: @CodeCaster I clicked the gem but the unicorn that popped up was mean to me. It urinated on the floor and bit me in my shoulder. You owe me an explanation and a new carpet. (Is [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/users/137537/boltclocks-a-unicorn) the unicorn you're talking about? I think it is a person, a human, not a unicorn. And he didn't pee on my floor.)

Comment: @KonradViltersten https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_vGK008c_rA

Comment: If necessary, retag the question with more relevant tags. An edit bumps it into activity lists and adding new valid tags gets new sets of eyeballs on the question.

Comment: @BSMP Maybe a direct link to the answer is best.

Comment: @becko - I agree; I missed that this was about the Late Answers queue specifically.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

If you truly found a hidden gem you want to reward with more than just an upvote, you can put a [bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) on the question and then manually award it to that answer after 24 hours.

The bounty would get the question more attention, which could also get the new answer more attention.  And the posts that were awarded bounties are clearly marked as such, so that's one more small thing to make the answer "shine."

Comment: Sure, this might be fine once in a while for folks with alot of rep, but it doesn't serve as a general solution. How many people will donate rep to an answer just to "make it shine"?

Comment: "_to reward with more than just an upvote_"  Besides, hidden gems are not the general solution.  They are the exception.

Comment: @Pacerier I would.

Comment: @Pacerier In fact, once past 20000, there is really no sense of hoarding more reputation, so people can become more generous with it, sharing it with others that did something extraordinary. And the call to "find hidden gems in late answers" is already directed to those who can share a bit of their 2k (or more) if there would be a gem to polish. So, many people might share, and it's good to encourage this behavior.

Comment: *In fact, once past 20000, there is really no sense of hoarding more reputation*  Yeah, repeat that when you get there :-)  My precious points, my precious, ...

Comment: @biziclop: there could be a downside in awarding bounties. It might *feel* like giving money as a gift (obviosly, rep is not money) i.e., it might shift the situation from social to business rules that discourages people from donating their knowledge and time.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian I don't quite follow you. If we give away reputation to strangers like we don't give away money, it makes rep work more like money? And if it does, how come huge tech companies donate their knowledge to open source projects then? Are they not in it for the money? I mean, I don't know if giving bounties is good or bad overall, but I certainly don't see rep as money and therefore I'd give it away much more freely.

Comment: @biziclop: I'm talking [about social vs. market norms: *"“Mom, for all the love you’ve put into this, how much do I owe you?”"*](http://danariely.com/the-books/excerpted-from-chapter-4-%E2%80%93-the-cost-of-social-norms/)

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian I see. Well, that's certainly one way of looking at it, though a peculiarly American way. But I wouldn't think we're talking about setting any kind of norm here, it's not like there will be hundreds of hidden gems found every day. As far as I can tell, this would be a nice but vanishingly rare gesture compared to the sheer volume of SO posts.

Comment: @biziclop rep is much harder to earn and more rewarding than money :p