# Add 'reward user' button (like on answers.unity for example)

Tags: feature-request, status-declined

I notice the jokers at answers.unity3d.com added a "reward user" button, you can do it on any post or answer

[Example](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/884762/ui-inputfield-caret-position-wrong-when-midline-al.html?page=1&pageSize=5&sort=votes)

[image]

Here on SO, as I understand it, **you can reward a contribution**, by giving a upvote: that gives the writer in question 10 (I believe) points.  Alternately, using the bounty system, after waiting 3 days and another 2 days, **you can reward a contribution** (actually, only answers) from your "own" points.

The "unity" button is identical to the bounty (it comes from your own points), but:

- you can just choose any amount (there's probably some sensible limits)
- no waiting

(Also I think you can do it to answers, questions, or even comments.)

I think this is a great idea.  You can click over 10, 100, 1000 or whatever you want points to reward a question or answer you admire.

Here on SO, you have to tediously use the lame, slow, "bounty" system to achieve the same goal.

Should the feature be tried here ?

---

Astoundingly, it would appear I have to spell out ***why it's good to get points***:

- people provide Answers, to get points.  (that's not an if and only if statement: of course there are other reason that people provide answers - sheer kindness, to impress, etc.  but the statement "people provide Answers, to get points" is a fact)
- the entire, total, model of the whole existence of SO is based on the idea "people provide Answers, to get points", so
- it does seem entirely confusing, to not see, instantly and completely, why this is a good idea.  ie: if you're saying it's whacky and not a good idea, you're saying "SO - the utter core of the entire concept of SO - is whacky and not a good idea"

--

"sockpuppet issue"

"umm", the current bounty system can be used, at any time, for "sockpuppet-funding"; the proposed idea (which is really nothing more than "bounties, with no delays, and choose any amount") would be exactly no more or less subject to this problem. (Assuming it's a problem.)

Comment: It's only tedious, lame and slow because it's about more than just the rep.

Comment: 24 hours isn't that slow.  And it also helps get the question more attention, which might also get the awesome answer more attention.  See also [What to do with hidden gems while reviewing?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/300677/4320665)

Comment: So you can reward a user with 10 points? Ain't that called... an upvote on an answer?

Comment: What does that button _do_?

Comment: This seems like an easy way to launder reputation between sock puppets.

Comment: @BradLarson - hmm, it's identical on that issue to Bounty.

Comment: Now you're just being willfully obtuse. How can you not see that the bounty system without restrictions or delays would *obviously* be abused more?

Comment: Also (BradL), a broader issue is .. "who cares"?  At the moment SO has a **tiny, arcane**, problem with "sockpuppets" (I would imagine only a handful of the most dedicated SO users even know what that is.)  So, the whole point of SO is rewards generate great answers.  If the idea at hand makes the whole system much more exciting, dynamic, and leads to much better answers - "who cares" about the sockpuppet issue? I'm sure they would be detected (socially and otherwise) anyways.

Comment: "SO has a **tiny, arcane**, problem with 'sockpuppets'" Haha... you would be surprised. Sure, most people aren't familiar with the term "sockpuppet". But most people understand the concept of cheating, many have a rough idea of how to cheat on SO in particular, and some (a non-trivial number) go on to do it.

Comment: @JoeBlow: no, it is not identical to a bounty, because a bounty *draws a lot of attention*, and you cannot insta-award it to avoid the attention.

Comment: @JoeBlow: and although I'm glad you think cheating is but a tiny problem, we work hard to keep it that way. We clean out plenty of cheaters every day, your proposal makes that job *harder*.

Answer (score 13):

In addition to the potential negative effects this could have, I don't see what *positive* effects it would bring about. Would this lead to better questions or more detailed answers than we're already getting? I don't think so. Great posts can already be rewarded with upvotes and bounties. I doubt that many people would choose to award more reputation bonuses just because they were awarded immediately. That might be a little bit better for the person *receiving* the bonus, but it doesn't really do that much for the person *giving* the bonus.

---

> the entire, total, model of the whole existence of SO is based on the idea "people provide Answers, to get points"

False. Stack Overflow isn't first and foremost a place to earn points. It's a place to ask questions and to share knowledge. The points are secondary, or maybe tertiary. Awarding more points doesn't make a post better.

Comment: Hmm, 100% pure conjecture.

Comment: @JoeBlow Much like your proposal.

Comment: It's about rewarding which in turn motivates answerer. Call it "mini-bounty", when you don't want/can't award full amount (starts from 50). As a user who just joined and have few points, I'd be more willing to give some away. Bounty is no-go unless you have enough to also keep your priviledges.

Answer (score 3):

Part of the reason we cannot just transfer reputation to other users without having to go through the bounty system is that transfers of reputation have been abused to "fund" sock puppets. (Even the bounty system, with its restrictions has been abuse for this.) There's a reason SO works in a certain way. It's not arbitrary but borne out of experience.

Perhaps it works on answers.unity3d.com because they are doing something significantly different from SO, which allows them to have this feature without the negative consequences. If it is the case, then someone who wants to see this happen on SO has to suggest not only this feature but the changes that would have to be made to make it work here.

Then again, perhaps answers.unity3d.com is okay with sock puppets, in which case it is not a model to emulate.

Comment: To be fair, we have no real evidence that this proposed feature would be any *more* likely to be abused than bounties already are. It may well be that, for those rare users who actually wish to transfer rep between sockpuppet accounts, the bounty system is already sufficient. More to the point, most of the sockpuppet rings I've heard about seem to have just focused on mutual upvoting. Nor is there any real reason to assume that the proposed reward system would be significantly harder to monitor for abuse than bounties are, especially if the rewards were publicly logged.

Comment: I put the burden of proof on the person making the proposal. If the proposal does not mention how the new feature would be monitored, I don't imagine a system for them. (It's okay for others to do so. It's just not what I do.) Nevertheless, a log system for insta-transfers would not benefit from the same attention that bounties do. Our thousands of users have an self-interest in looking at bountied question and try to get the reward. Whatever interest there is in looking at a log of insta-transfers I'm sure is dwarfed by the interest in looking at bountied questions.

Comment: Hmm, I get the sense that "The Sockpuppet Issue", which is a total irrelevancy, a non-issue, is a hot-button topic for insiders at SO. That's a shame; it's the sort of very tedious "old-person" thinking that hide-bounds a system.

Comment: (It's so trivially obvious that one could add "safeguards" and heuristics against bogus payments it's not really worth mentioning ... but it does seem to be a "hot button" issue.  A shame.)

Comment: @JoeBlow Just because you don't see how widespread it is doesn't mean it isn't a problem. If we don't deal with the sock puppet issue, reputation will become meaningless.

Comment: To be fair though, all the bounty system does about this is slow it down. The same can be done, and likely does happen, and likely gets mostly handled automatically.

Comment: Hi Kevin.  "..reputation will become meaningless."  That's a complete assertion.  It's hard to see it.  Look at the figures of actual senior insiders here -- 100,000s points.  Or look at other systems, say wikipedia: they have a tiny, irrelevant sockpuppet problem (ok, one entry, "global warming!" is all f'ed-up! :) ) and they have almost no "anti-sock" systems (I think?)  It's hard to see it as an issue at all.

Comment: I'm not familiar with any of those other systems so I can't really comment on that.

Comment: Just as you say - one can trivially launder the odd 500, maybe 1000 points using the current "bounty" system.  Say the limit on "reward button" was 500 just the same.  What possible damage could be done?  Some fool spends a year building up 1000 points and .. gives it to his cousin.  So what?

Comment: Right, it happens, and gets dealt with. I don't think that's really a good argument against this feature. I still don't think we need the feature though.

Comment: @KevinB Regarding automatic systems, I'm sure they are in place and work but I've seen cases on Meta that were brought up by people looking at bountied questions and noticing something amiss. The visibility given to bountied questions helps catch things that would not be otherwise caught.

Comment: HI Louis - on the contrary. All cases of "sockpuppeting" end up with one simple end result ....... some idiot being rude or obtuse on a question.  ("I agree with that guy - you suck!"  :) )  It would be completely impossible to farm out enough "SP"s to say influence a vote here or some such (and the simplest heuristics would find the issue instantly and trivially).  SO is now far too big, voting publics are now too large and so on, for "SP"s to be anything more than a minor nuisance.  Much like say "someone swearing".

Comment: Note that, for example, the system already bans serial upvoting.  (When you really like someone's answer, so you quickly upvote their last ten answers.)  Fair enough.  That would work perfectly if bounties were instant (which is really all the "reward!" button is; plus you can enter any digit amount from 1 to 500).

Comment: @JoeBlow I'd really like to see some hard charted data instead of assumptions.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think the sock puppet argument is really that important with this feature. Yes, it can make it easier for sock puppets to do what they do, but if it's done on any large scale, it will eventually get caught and dealt with.

I do however question the need for rewarding users directly. This site is not a social network. It isn't about users, rewards, or making a profit, it's about getting good quality answers to good quality questions that will be useful for a period of time. Rewarding a single user doesn't help toward that goal.

If a question or answer is really that good, rewarding it should involve upvoting it and/or awarding a bounty to it. The "Reward" button you are suggesting won't do anything to promote the content unless it gets displayed the same way that a bounty reward does, and at that point, how is it any different than a bounty reward other than the fact that it doesn't move the question to the "Featured" list?

I would argue such a feature would be *less* useful than a bounty. It might even be less rewarding; even if you choose to give 500 rep reward instead of a 100 rep bounty, if it's a quality post, it may gain double that in upvotes due to the increased visibility over a period of time. The reward may not be instant, but it'll come over time if it deserves it.

Comment: HI Kevin, I fully agree with your first paragraph  :)  Re your second paragraph.  Hmm, I'm honestly struggling to understand the logic: the **"whole reason" I provide answers** is that I get some points if the answer is ultimately "ticked" (actually, I often tell new users who have thanked me for an answer, "please for goodness sake tick my answer since I need the points!")  I actually really like giving points away (I mean bounties - check my record). Indeed, I often specifically sit down and say "Hmm, if I put in 30 minutes answering some Qs in topics I'm expert in, that will....

Comment: ...generate some points for me, now and over time!  Let's put the time in!"  Again, I'm rather explaining the obvious.  Sure, people do answer for other reasons (just to be pure nice, etc) but in general it seems sort of self-contradictory in the SO milieu to say, as you have Kevin, "people will not be motivated to provide answers by a point reward" -- that's sort of the whole nature of SO!

Comment: I understand that point of view, I felt the same way before i had 30k points. I answered questions because i gained a reward from it, But, that's the beauty of stackoverflow! It's point system and moderation system guided me to doing what the system needed me to do: provide quality answers to quality quesitons. because doing so gives enormous amounts of reputation. I still get daily reputation from questions i answered 2+ years ago.

Comment: Regarding your now 4th paragraph: **I couldn't agree more!!!** When I get an incredibly useful answer [example!!](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32633406/294884) I want to **BOTH** click Martin there 100 points, to say thanks AND as you say add a bounty to give Martin much-deserved "advertising value".

Comment: (And of course, when I say give Martin 100 points "to thank him" -- of course the incidental economic effect is that, users see that if they supply awesome answers, they will from time to time get such payments.  Which is, of course - again to state the obvious - the total mechanism at work when users make a big effort to provide a great answer for bountied questions.)  (And indeed, it's the entire mechanism of "economics"!  :) )

Comment: If you could award a bounty instantly, would that be the same effect as this feature request?

Comment: Regarding your point about points over time, questions from 2 years ago.  I couldn't agree more, and again "my" suggestion couldn't be more in tune with this.  I'd love it if great answers got the occasional 5, 10, 100 point "tip" for all time over the years.

Comment: well, that would have been closed as a dupe for one, it's been asked for and declined many times because the point of a bounty is to bring attention to the question, and instantly awarding it goes against that.

Comment: Actually no that's not what I'm saying ... as people here have clarified, the **raison d'etre of the bounty system** is the "advertising value".  And that's all good.  What I suggest here is just a straightforward reward; nothing to do with advertising a question, getting more attention, etc.  (That's a separate, worthwhile, issue - handled by the "bounty/'featured'" system.)

Comment: You're quite right, our posts crossed.  Adding a "reward" button has nothing to do with the (excellent) "Featured" system.